# Compatibility of .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256 algorithm on iOS with Java

Tags: java, ios, swift, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to communicate from an iOS application to a Java backend. When using the `.rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256` algorithm in `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` for [encryption](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption), the backend shows the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Exception thrown while invoking doFinal(byte[]).
    at  ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:497)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:292)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:366)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:392)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2207)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

The Java backend is using the `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` algorithm from the `SunJCE` provider. This provider uses `SHA-1` for the **MGF1** digest. However the default for iOS is to use `SHA-256`.

- How can I change this in the code for iOS to make this compatible?

**Note:** To be clear, the exact same interaction is currently working fine with `.rsaEncryptionPKCS1` on iOS where the backend uses `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` in Java.

Comment: I could update the Java cipher to use `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256`, but unfortunately that isn't supported by Android, so I would rather re-configure the OAEP parameter spec on iOS.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried `.rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA1`? Not sure if that sets the MGF or only the hash function for the message...

Comment: .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA1 - doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, from what I've researched & experimented with, it's practically impossible to support RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding on iOS.

Similiar issue: [Encrypt RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237524/encrypt-rsa-ecb-oaepwithsha-256andmgf1padding-swift)

But this only addressed the algorithm but not the padding issue.

Comment: While there is an answer to this question, it would be better if the main part of the answer is on the post.